# Independent Probability with Parking Spots

Tags: probability

Two students, Alfred and Barbara, are fed-up with the inequity in the parking situation on campus, particularly the Provost's cushy parking spot right next to the student center food court.  They know that the Provost always goes out for lunch and that no one monitors the spot while she is away.  So Alfred and Barbara decide to take turns parking in the Provosts spot during the lunch hour so they wont have to walk far to get food and to "make a point".

They know that the Provost does return early on purpose to catch this sort of thing, choosing to do so with uniform and independent probability 1/6.  They also know that the penalty for getting caught is the loss of parking privileges for all of campus.  Nevertheless, they are committed to doing this until one of them gets caught.  Alfred agrees to go first.

What is the probability that Alfred will be the one who is caught?  How many days can they expect to play this game before one of them is caught?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I suggest rephrasing this as a math problem, trimming out all the unnecessary verbiage.  I think, then, you'll find it to be quite easy.

Comment: For instance: "$A$ and $B$ are alternating throws of a fair die. The winner is the first to get a $6$.  What is the probability that  the player who goes first will eventually win?  How many tosses are expected until the first $6$ is observed?"

Answer (score 1):

$$P(Alfred) = \frac 16 + \frac 16 (\frac 56)^2 + \frac 16 (\frac 56)^4 + ... $$

$$= \frac 16 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac {25}{36})^n  = \frac 6{11}$$

$$E(D) =     \frac 16 +2 \frac 16 (\frac 56) + 3\frac 16 (\frac 56)^2 + ... $$

$$= \frac 16 \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(\frac {5}{6})^{n-1}   = 6$$
Where I have used the result...
$$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\;x^{n-1}  = \frac 1{(1-x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

*An approach avoiding summation of an infinite series*

Let the probability that $A$ ultimately gets caught be $a$

A is either caught on the first try or is back to square $1$ if neither $A$ nor $B$ are caught on the first try

$Thus\;\; a = \frac16 + \frac56\frac56a\;$ which yields $a= \frac6{11}$

Let $d$ be the # of days game can be played before one of them is caught,

then $d = 1 + \frac56d$, which yields $d = 6$